# Adding role name to Application Insights telemetry

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I use this code to log an exception using the `TelemetryClient`:

```
var appInsightsRoleName = "tracking";

var telemetry = new ExceptionTelemetry();
telemetry.Exception = exception;
telemetry.SeverityLevel = SeverityLevel.Error;
telemetry.Context.InstrumentationKey = appInsightsKey;
telemetry.Context.Operation.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
telemetry.Properties.Add("cloud_RoleName", appInsightsRoleName);

var ai = new TelemetryClient();
ai.TrackException(telemetry);
```

The role name is set by setting the `cloud_RoleName` property.

The exception is successfully logged into app insights, but the problem is its role name is not propagated into app insights:

[image]

The exception is logged under `no role name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the [`cloud_RoleName` is populated by the global `Context.Cloud` property on the `TelemetryClient` Object.](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/91e9c91fcea979b1eec4e31ba8e0fc683bf86802/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/Extensibility/Implementation/CloudContext.cs)

You can set it after creating the `TelemetryClient` by doing `ai.Context.Cloud.RoleName` (sudo code, may differ between app insights SDK version) then it will be set for all events output by the client through it's lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

ApplicationInsights picks up the role name from the environment variable `WEBSITE_HOSTNAME`.

This is done in `AzureAppServiceRoleNameFromHostNameHeaderInitializer`

In Azure, this variable is set by default and ApplicationInsights will automatically strip the suffix ".azurewebsites.net".

In other environments, you can set this environment variable yourself to avoid the empty role name in ApplicationInsights.